# Find missing number in a sequence not sorted

Tags: java, string, numbers, character, complexity-theory

I have to find a missing number in a sequence not sorted. This sequence is stored in a String object. For example, in this sequence: `3 1 6 5 2` the missing number is `4`. 
Between every number there is a `\n`. I have to do this without using structures as Array, Dictionary, Lists etc because I need to have a O(1) complexity.
In input i receive also the max number of the sequence (in the example sequence, i receive the number 6)
Any idea?

Comment: Show us your code or how far you tried to do this problem.

Comment: A complexity of O(1) is only possible with an upper limit of the sequence length. Otherwise you are stuck with O(n*log n) (i.e. sort first and look for the missing number). Or maybe O(n) if you do not care about space.

Comment: Compare the sum of the sequence to the sum of the integers between the min and max values.

Comment: @Ctx i forgot to say that in input i receive also the max number of the sequence (in the example sequence, i receive the number 6)

Answer (score 0):

METHOD 1(Use sum formula)
Algorithm:

> 1. Get the sum of numbers 
>         total = n*(n+1)/2    -----------O(1)
>
> > 2  Subtract all the numbers from sum and
> >        you will get the missing number

```
 void ans(int total){     ///O(1)

            big_total = (n+1)*(n+2)/2;  //  n+1 because 1 number is missing

            return (big_total-total);


     }




input_array()
{
  int n,total=0,i;

  cout<<"enter no of element";
  cin>>n;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
     cin>>arr[i];
     total+=arr[i];
   }

   cout<<ans(total);

}
```

Comment: shouldn't your big total be n*((n+1)/2) ?

Comment: lets say `n=4` than `arr[]={1,3,4,5} ` than we have use `n+1` because one number is missing so total numbers are  `5`

Comment: Yeah but the question says not allowed to use an Array and max number is giving. So max number should n and no need for the array.